# Open OBJ files with OpenGL c++

Tags: c++

I need some help because i'm trying to open a obj file with Code Blocks.
Im already downloaded the requirements for OpenGL and GLUT libraries.
somebody knows some basic and specific steps to do it?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: opengl doesn't have a file format, you need to parse the file yourself (or google parsing obj)

Answer (score 0):

OBJ is a fairly simple file format to read. But if you want to do a little bit more I found Assimp to be a good starting place. It's obviously an API that reads in a whole lot of 3d file formats. (I use .dae  (Collada)) Setting up is fairly simple, download, link to project, then code.

Here are the includes

```
#include <assimp\scene.h>
#include <assimp\Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp\postprocess.h>
```

Here is the general code to read in

```
 const aiScene* aiscene = importer.ReadFile(fileName, aiProcess_OptimizeMeshes
    | aiProcess_Triangulate);
```

Then aiscene is a this big complex data structure holding whatever it is you need. (You might need to add some extra flags there depending on things like left handed or right handed coordinate system)
http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_downloads.html